# if(checkbox.Checked){} issues

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement, checkbox, checked

I am not sure why but I opened a new project and I am trying to do a simple checkbox + button + console write statement and I am getting an error. 
The error states:
RoutedEventHandler System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.Checked
The event ToggleButton.Checked can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=.

I used this code before without any issues so I am not sure what's happening...

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(checkBox1.Checked)
        {
          Console.Write("Checked");
        }
    }
```

Comment: IsChecked?.....

Comment: As I said, I literally used the exact same line elsewhere and it worked. So I am not sure what happened.

Comment: No, it isn't, read the question.

Comment: You are probably confusing it with the [`Checked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the WinForms CheckBox. In WPF, the property is `IsChecked`.

Comment: I am looking at the code from the previous project:
if (checkbox2.Checked){}

And it runs/compiles just fine. I wish I could put up a screenshot on here...

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity... can you show us a fully working code that uses `Checked` instead of `IsChecked`?

Comment: @PhilZan Certainly that was WinForms, not a WPF project. Are you even  aware that these are different frameworks?

Comment: `EDIT: before more idiots mark this as a duplicate` sounds like man in the Mirror Syndrome, don't call others what one maybe appearing to call themselves..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Checked` is an event (that's why an exception is being thrown when your code looks for an handler subscription, [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked(v=vs.110).aspx)), `IsChecked` is a `Boolean` and it's probably the property you are looking for ([MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx)). Your code should look like this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((bool)checkBox1.IsChecked)
        Console.Write("Checked");
}
```

Comment: That is sort of what I was looking for and i'll take it as an answer.

However, IsChecked will return a bool? != bool error so the more proper coding would be (checkbox1.IsChecked == true). Never found a way around it.

Comment: Why should you ever perform a check over booleans equality? This code excerpt is 100% working, and there is no need to perform a boolean comparison since the if statement works against a boolean.

Comment: To perform the opposite check you just need `if (!checkBox1.IsChecked)`.

Comment: When I use your code as is, i get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type bool? to bool. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)."

The only work around i found was to perform a check. Is there any condition that must be set prior to not have to check?

Comment: The error message is telling you what to do. Write `if ((bool)checkBox1.IsChecked)`